# Dropping an element into the body below its height

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a jsfiddle here - http://jsfiddle.net/az47U/3/ - with a Gallery div 
and a Canvas div, both sitting in the body. Both divs are absolutely positioned so they don't
contribute anything to the body height. I've given the body a  100px height just to give it some presence.  The Gallery div has a red draggable box and the Canvas and body are both droppables that will accept that box. Droppables turn brown when the red box is over them.

My question is, how do I drop the red box into the body at "X", or at any point that is below the 100px defined height?

X ***is*** in the body because when I drop the red box in the top 100px of the body that 
area gets the brown hover color. You can also see "X" in the DOM between the `<body>` . . .`</body>` tags.

Thanks

```
<div id="gallery">Gallery
    <div id="redBox"></div>
</div>
<div id="canvas">Canvas</div>
<div id="x">X</div>
```

Comment: X is an element within the body, but it is an element that is not marked as a droppable. Wouldn't you need to mark it as a droppable (accepted) before it will accept the draggable?

Comment: I don't really want to drop it on the X element. I just tossed in "X" to mark a place on the body where I want to drop. Basically I want to drop the red box in the body by dropping at any place below the 100px defined height.

Comment: Could whoever downvoted my question provide some explanation?  They seem to assume that I don't know about body height and that's the 
simple solution.  I _do_ know about body height and that's _not_ the solution. The question is how to drop an element in the body at a point _below_ the body height.  Increasing the body height is not the answer.

Comment: Hi Steve -- can you clarify why the canvas div must be outside the flow of the body element (ie absolutely positioned)?

Answer (score 0):

Give your body more height. The "X" is outside the flow of the body element, which is only 100px tall in this scenario. X, for your intended purpose, is outside the body.

For instance, you could position the `canvas` div as relative, give it a `top` value of 0 to keep it at the top of the `body`, and then your `body` height would match the height of the `canvas` div no matter how many unknown elements get dropped into it.

```
div#canvas {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
}
```

Comment: The question is, "How can I drop an element in the body at a point below the body's defined height?". The answer is not "Change the height."  The application here is a site builder where people are constantly creating and adding new content to the Canvas div.  At any time they need to be able to come over to the left of the last element they added and drop an image into the wings area at that depth and "hit" the body, so the image is properly added to the body. I have no idea how deep the canvas will be when they do that so I can't set an arbitrary height for the body.